# stream audio from browser to WebRTC native C++ application

Tags: c++, webrtc

I manged to run WebRTC peerconnection example, but it is not running on the browser. 
I'm trying to find a way to stream both video and audio from browser to my native program.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. WebRTC is designed to work in a peer-to-peer manner between two WebRTC agents (typically a Web Browser). Your native program needs to become the second peer.

If you need to rely on open source components a good starting point is:

- OpenSSL for the DTLS key exchange.
- libsrtp to encrypt the RTP packets.
- ffmpeg to decode the PCM audio from the browser (libvpx if you need to do video).

You'll also need to handle the ICE negotiation which requires processing STUN messages. Also extract the media payloads from the RTP packets. All these steps are also after you've determined a signalling method to exchange the SDP offer and answer between you app and the browser.

As you've probably realised starting from scratch it's a major task. There are probably some commercial libraries that will do the job and save you a lot of pain.

If that doesn't scare you and you do still want to make an attempt using open source components this [example](https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/blob/master/MFWebCamWebRTC/MFWebCamWebRTC.cpp) "may" help. The sample is doing the reverse of what you've asked and is sending a video stream to Chrome rather than receiving an audio stream. The useful aspect is the connection negotiation. The sample program is able to get RTP packets flowing which is often the main problem.

The example is also using Windows Media Foundation which is Windows specific. It also has lots of shortcuts particularly with the RTP and STUN packet processing.